# Telethon, TelegramClient.connect how do I set authentication code programmatically

Tags: python, telethon

I am using telethon to automate some tasks on Telegram.
I am trying to create an API where third party users can provide phone number and enter code through an api. I have got the phone number part working, As I allow users to input their phone number through a webservice, this gets wrote to a file, then I am opening that file and fetching the phone number in python which is {number}, I then connect to the client using below.

```
client = TelegramClient(f'{number}', API_ID, API_KEY)
try:
    await client.connect()
except Exception as e:
    print('Failed to connect', e, file=sys.stderr)
    return
```

Once the code is run the user enters the verification code (not in the python app) which gets wrote to a file.

And in python the following is returned

```
Please enter the code you received:
```

I can open the file which contains the verification code which as {code}
but how do I use {code} to reply to 'Please enter the code you received:'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you get the code on telegram and not in the file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but this will be very complex as the code is sent to another device. You can write custom Telegram client that will send this code to your program, but it is too complex and in 99.9% of cases you won't need it.

**Edit:**

If you already have this code, let's say in `code` variable, you can try to use method `sign_in()` instead of `connect()`

```
try:
    await client.sign_in(number, code)
except Exception as e:
    print('Failed to connect', e, file=sys.stderr)
    return
```

[Reference for sign_in() in docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.auth.AuthMethods.sign_in)

Comment: Hi @David, so the code is received on another device, the owner submits the code to app (webservice), which writes the code to a file which I can access. I can view the code, manually enter the code or return the code in my script. But Its the automatically inputting the code here 'Please enter the code you received:', which I am unsure how to do. Do you know what I should be searching for to pass the {code} back in to the python output? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure whether it works, since I'm not able to try it myself right now. Please keep me up to date with your tries. I'll try myself when I'll be able to.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the help. Just found the client.sign_in(number, code) function. I think this will work. I will try and let you know. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
phone = "+123456789"

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
client.sign_in(phone)  # send code                                                 
try:
   code = input('enter code: ') # here instead of using input('enter code: ') you can just pass in the code they gave.
   client.sign_in(phone=phone, code=code)
   print(f'Successfully signed in as: {client.get_me().first_name} {client.get_me().last_name}')
except Exception as e:
   print(f'Sign-in failed: {e}')
```